# conditional rendering react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am making an advertising website with reusable components that load with different graphics depending on what page it is. I am using react-router-dom Route exact path.  I imagine i need to be able to read the state of that with my useEffect,[]. So how do i pass down the state  so its able to be read by the component.

Please note that the component Hero appears in the functions for Home, Consultants and Solutions

```
const Hero = props => {
 useEffect(() => {
  console.log(props);
 }, []);
 return (
  <Fragment>
   <div className='grid-hero'>
    <Fragment>
     <div className='overlay'>
      <div>
       <p className='bg-dark'></p>
       <img src={{ homeimg } || { consimg } || { solsimg }} alt='' />
      </div>
     </div>
    </Fragment>
```

```
  <Router>
   <Fragment>
    <Navbar />

    <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
     <Route exact path='/consultants' component={Consultants} />
     <Route exact path='/solutions' component={Solutions} />
     <Route exact path='/contactus' component={ContactUs} />"
    </Switch>
   </Fragment>
  </Router>
```

```
    <div
    className={
     {pathname === "/" && ("grid-home")}
     {pathname === "/consultants" && ("grid-consultants")}
     {pathname === "/solutions" && ("grid-solutions")}
    }>
```

Comment: I don't see any state here.

Comment: i need to i guess drill it in i think from the app level is what im asking for help with do i need to bring in useContext is that what you are saying?

Comment: What is "app level". Its unclear what the specific problem is. Are you unsure of how to pass props to a `Route` component?

Comment: i just need to be able to look and see that okay when im on /solutions okay heres the piece of react router being passed in that says its loaded /solutions.  i dont think i have to do it with context so basically yes id like to pass the route property into the Hero state on mount

Comment: Where does `Hero` fit in to this? Is that supposed to be `Home`?

Comment: Hero is a component in home, solutions and consultants

Comment: Did you console log `props` in those components? They will get three automatically - match, history, and location. It sounds like that's what you're looking for.

Comment: ive now passed props in on the functional level for home, consultants, solutions and hero and get an empty object

Comment: i understand what i need to do i need to add the prop match or whatever in the Hero component on Home. i just couldnt find those 3 items cause... well im a little green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you're looking for:

I've added Hero as top-level image component where your image would switch. I don't have the images, so I used strings, but if you import images like JSX, you'll be able to use this code by removing the `img` strings inside my Hero dummy component.

adding reference image import syntax for help:

```
import img from './img.png';
```

complete example:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contactus">ContactUs</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/solutions">Solutions</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Hero />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/contactus" component={ContactUs} />
        <Route path="/solutions" component={Solutions} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const Hero = () => {
  const homeimg = "HOME_IMAGE";
  const consimg = "CONTACT_US_IMAGE";
  const solsimg = "SOLUTIONS_IMAGE";
  let img = null;

  const location = useLocation();
  if (location.pathname === "/") img = homeimg;
  else if (location.pathname === "/contactus") img = consimg;
  else if (location.pathname === "/solutions") img = solsimg;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h3>{location.pathname}</h3>
      <div className="grid-hero">
        <Fragment>
          <div className="overlay">
            <div>
              <p className="bg-dark" />
              {img}
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function ContactUs() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>ContactUs</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Solutions() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Solutions</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

[codepen-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-1b7z2)

Comment: i like it... useLocation... I googled for hours on forking hooks for conditional rendering :X

Comment: hi it has helped but here is a problem im having with this.

I need to now use this to dynamically insert className string values and ive tried every iteration of string or variable and nothing works.

see the original post at the bottom for my latest code

Comment: @Mickey Gray create a new question as that is not related to the original